# Why we use Deferred() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

would you please tell me what is the purpose of using  $.Deferred() JQuery's Object with it's predefined methods, in functions with javascript. I've read the API but I didn't understand the goal exactly.
Thank you

Comment: This is a great video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juRtEEsHI9E

Answer (score 2):

you can follow this one 
[Asynchronous vs synchronous execution, what does it really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean?lq=1)

simply for asynchronous call you can use $.ajax and if you gonna need result in synchronous way then you can use $.Deferred()